# Main not compiling due to foldr

Tags: haskell, program-entry-point

I've added this code to f.hs file :

```
main = foldr (+) (0) [1,2,3]
```

when I use :

```
:l f.hs
```

I receive error :

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( f.hs, interpreted )

f.hs:1:14:
    No instance for (Num (IO t0)) arising from a use of ‘+’
    In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘(+)’
    In the expression: foldr (+) (0) [1, 2, 3]
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = foldr (+) (0) [1, 2, 3]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I want to use trace and see output of fold.

Why is this code not compiling ?

Comment: Haskell isn't C, `main` doesn't return an `Int`, it *must* return an `IO t`.

Comment: `foldr` _can_ return an `IO t`, but only if the type of the first argument is `a -> IO t -> IO t`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main` has type `IO ()` while `foldr (+) (0) [1,2,3]` has type `Num a => a`. GHC tries to combine these but fails, since `Num` is not defined on `IO a`. Presumably, you want to print the result. Try this

```
main = print $ foldr (+) (0) [1,2,3]
```

Then, once you load into GHCi, you can call `main` to get `6`.

Comment: I tried to provide more detailed explanation in my answer on why `IO` is inferred here as type. Maybe this also helps.

Comment: The type of `main` needs to unify with `IO a`; it need not actually be `IO ()`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you! I've been trying to wrap my head around code I thought shouldn't work but did - it all suddenly makes sense.

Comment: @Alec, I recommend giving `main` the type `IO ()` if it is intended to run and then terminate normally, to make it clear that it produces an uninteresting value. If it is only supposed to stop from an uncaught exception, I'd give it the polymorphic type `IO a` to make it clear that it does not produce a value.

Answer (score 3):

The type of main should unify with type `IO a`. But type of `foldr (+) (0) [1,2,3]` is `Num a => a`.

You could modify your program like this:

```
-- Note print return a value of type IO ()
main :: IO ()
main = print $ foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]
```

Comment: The type of `main` needs to unify with `IO a`; it need not actually be `IO ()`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, you are right. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce and solve the problem. I found http://www.quora.com/Why-cant-functions-be-defined-on-the-GHCi-repl which gave me the hint:
It seems like the REPL is "a do block in the IO monad." as stated in the other answers. 
The do notation can be used to express a series of monadic expressions executed one after another. As [it can be seen at Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation), it can be translated into a chain of monad `bind` operations.

Hence you have two options:

One is to let main have the signature `main :: IO ()`, so that

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ foldr (+) (0) [1,2,3]

evaluateTwice :: IO()
evaluateTwice = do 
              main
              main
-- equvalent alternative as monadic bind operations, see Wikibooks
evaluateTwice = main >>= \ x1 -> main
```

would chain two calls to `main` of the `IO` monad(using bind), returning a new instance of the `IO` monad. This is what the other posters basically suggested.

Alternatively you can use `let`

```
let main = foldr (+) (0) [1,2,3]
```

which defines a "variable".